# How do I Use an If statement within JSON Adaptive card for Teams to @mention user on Submitted Choice Response?

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I've already built the card and it works in teams the way I want it to. I just can't figure out how to pass the result back to Teams with power automate or use a if statement after the submission of the choice set to @mention the individual.  Effectively I want to use the choice set in the adaptive card to either notify another individual in teams or not.  I believe I have to have the if statement with the choice set result within the card as the data cannot be passed out to Power Automate, correct?  Where do I insert the if statement?  [image: Visualizer Result]

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Appointment Booked For @{triggerOutputs()?['body/from']}",
        "id": "Title",
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "color": "Accent"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/subject']}",
        "id": "acHeaderTagLine",
        "separator": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Notify Accounting?",
        "weight": "Bolder",
        "size": "ExtraLarge",
        "spacing": "None",
        "id": "acHeader"
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "@{outputs('Get_@mention_token_for_Onboarding')?['body/atMention']}: blah blah blah instructions",
        "id": "acInstructions",
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Notify Accounting?",
        "id": "acQuestion"
    },
    {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "placeholder": "Select from these choices",
        "choices": [
            {
                "title": "Yes, Notify Accounting",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "title": "No, this is an exception",
                "value": "0"
            }
        ],
        "id": "acChoices",
        "style": "expanded"
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit",
        "id": "btnSubmit"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You can't use if statement in the adaptive card. You can use [Action.ToggleVisibility](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html) you can perform actions when user clicks on the button. Try if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use if statement in the adaptive card. You can use [Action.ToggleVisibility](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html) you can perform actions when user clicks on the button

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  ToggleVisibility and showcard is the closest I can get to what I want but showcard doesn't allow dynamic content use preventing me from toggling the visibility on unnessessary parts and then adding a new segment to the card to at someone.  It just displays the code without being able to execute it.  Any ideas or did I hit a limitation?

Comment: Currently dynamic data is not supported by  Action.ToggleVisibilty. this is by design.